# Question about the notation of a matrix that represents a linear transformation T

Tags: notation, linear-transformations

Let $T: R^3 \rightarrow R^3$ be a linear transformation such that $T(x,y,z) = (x,0,0)$. Which implies that the matrix that represents the transformation is \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
Which of these would be the correct way to name the matrix?

$T= \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ or $[T] = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$
or perhaps none of them are right? I'm getting extremely confused with the notation. Tried to search online for awhile for an answer but I've been unable to find a proper answer regarding the notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your book/the context.

If the context is such that matrices assume the standard basis and stand for the corresponding linear transformation, then the first (writing that $T$ is the matrix) is fine.

If we distinguish matrices from linear transformations but assume the standard basis when one is not specified, then the second $[T]$ might be more appropriate.

If we need to specify the basis always, and $\mathcal E$ represents the standard basis, then you should probably write something like $[T]_{\mathcal E}$ instead of either.

In general, context typically makes it clear.

Comment: In the case that T represents a matrix and not [T] how does it work with the way that T is defined as T(x,y,z) = (x,0,0) since in that case T is a 3x3 matrix multiplied by a 1x3 vector which is undefined, or is the convention just to treat it as a column vector when needed?

Comment: @ShayY Again, this depends on convention (and laziness). I’d argue that you need to write the vectors as columns (or indicate that they're to be transposed) if you want to use $T$ for the matrix itself but many authors will (usually rightfully) claim that the given notation is sufficiently clear.

Answer (score 1):

Like what the other poster said, it depends on the context and the chosen convention of the authors.
I’ve seen matrices written with and without brackets around the letter so it’s up to you/the teacher.

There rarely is one “true” convention for any particular math concept.